# How to Convert the output of the Query to more than 1 HTML Table for send in Mail

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am having the automation setup which will run the batch file every 10mins, so the report will send the results in HTML Format,i can able to get the output if the record size is smaller ex:10rows, if the records or more then i am able to see only minimum data, ex: if i had 30 rows of data to send in mail then this below code is displaying 15rows and also it misleading the arrangement with first table and heading ,

```
DECLARE @xmlone NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @bodyone NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xmlone = CAST(( SELECT 
[Instance] AS 'td','',
[Direction] AS 'td','',
[SouthEast] AS 'td','', 
[SOuthCentral] AS 'td','',
SouthWest AS 'td'
FROM ErrorValues
Where Instance ='Support'  
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SET @bodyone ='<html><body><H3>Maximum Error Value </H3>
<head><style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th> Instance </th> 
<th> Direction </th> 
<th> SouthEast </th> 
<th> SouthCentral </th>  
<th> SouthWest </th></tr>'    

SET @bodyone = @bodyone + @xmlone +'</table></body></html>'
Print @bodyone

GO
print '==================================================================================================================='


DECLARE @xmltwo NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @bodytwo NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xmltwo = CAST(( SELECT 
[SerName] AS 'td','',
[IPAddress] AS 'td','',
[SName] AS 'td','', 
[Status] AS 'td','',
[Error Count] AS 'td'
FROM  SServiceDown  
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


SET @bodytwo ='<html><body><H2>Error Count</H2>
<table> 
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> Error count </th> </tr>'    


SET @bodytwo = @bodytwo + @xmltwo +'</table></body></html>'
Print @bodytwo
GO

Print '==================================================================================================================='

DECLARE @xmlthree NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @bodythree NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xmltwo = CAST(( SELECT 
[SerName] AS 'td','',
[IPAddress] AS 'td','',
[SName] AS 'td','', 
[Status] AS 'td','',
[TimeTaken] AS 'td','',
[MName] AS 'td','',
[TTime] AS 'td'
FROM  Gold10
ORDER BY TTaken DESC  
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


SET @bodythree ='<html><body><H3>Web Report</H3>
<table> 
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> TTaken </th> 
<th> MName </th> 
<th> TTime </th> </tr>'    

SET @bodythree = @bodythree + @xmlthree +'</table></body></html>'
Print @bodythree
Go
```

My Expected Result should return all the records in the particular table
but i am getting only partial records and also misleading the alignment heading

Expected-

```
<html><body><H3>Maximum Error count </H3>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th> Cluster </th> 
<th> Direction   </th> 
<th> SouthSouthEast </th> 
<th> SouthSouthCentral </th>  
<th> SouthSouthWest </th></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>SouthSouthWest(RSM)</td><td>11</td><td>12.6</td><td>10.99</td></tr></table></body></tbody></html>





===================================================================================================================
<html><body><H3>Web  Report</H3>
<body>
<head><style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<table> 
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> TTaken </th> 
<th> MName </th> 
<th> TTime </th> </tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test Finish</td><td>45.000000</td><td>SouthEast</td><td> 2:57:24.81</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.099131</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.031256</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:58 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.941930</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:04 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.937502</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:41 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>state</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.812501</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:17 AM</td></tr><tr><td></table>
```

I am Getting;-

```
<html><body><H3>Maximum Error count </H3>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th> Cluster </th> 
<th> Direction   </th> 
<th> SouthSouthEast </th> 
<th> SouthSouthCentral </th>  
<th> SouthSouthWest </th></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>SouthSouthWest(RSM)</td><td>11</td><td>12.6</td><td>10.99</td></tr></table></body></tbody></html>





===================================================================================================================
<html><body><H3>Web  Report</H3>
<body>
<head><style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<table> 
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> TTaken </th> 
<th> MName </th> 
<th> TTime </th> </tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test Finish</td><td>45.000000</td><td>SouthEast</td><td> 2:57:24.81</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.099131</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.031256</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:58 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.941930</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:04 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.937502</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:41 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.
```

Some times i am getting the output Like below as well.

```
<html><body><H3>Web  Report</H3>
<html><body><H3>Maximum Error count </H3>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th> Cluster </th> 
<th> Direction   </th> 
<th> SouthSouthEast </th> 
<th> SouthSouthCentral </th>  
<th> SouthSouthWest </th></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>SouthSouthWest(RSM)</td><td>11</td><td>12.6</td><td>10.99</td></tr></table></body></tbody></html>







<body>
<head><style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<table> 
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> TTaken </th> 
<th> MName </th> 
<th> TTime </th> </tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test Finish</td><td>45.000000</td><td>SouthEast</td><td> 2:57:24.81</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>HP</td><td>Test end</td><td>43.000000</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:47.52</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.099131</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>2.031256</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:58 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.957105</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:06 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.941930</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:57:04 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.937502</td><td>SouthEast</td><td>02:56:41 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>District</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.930133</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:08 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.899180</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.895235</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:21 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>SOAP</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.875342</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:12 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.869292</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:36 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.859384</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:19 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>XML</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.858262</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:32 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthWest</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.0.1</td><td>REST</td><td>PASS</td><td>1.857935</td><td>SouthCentral</td><td>10:32:29 AM</td></tr><tr><td>SouthSouthWest1</td><td>127.0.
===================================================================================================================
```

Comment: So what exactly the problem is? Did you get any error or what ?

Comment: no Error, i am not getting the Second HTML Table , it showing only the first query with HTML Tags as a output, for second one no reaction.

Comment: The reason you don't get any result of second query is - there might be `null` values in any of the columns of `SameServiceDown` table. Verify it by - `Select * from SameServiceDown`

Comment: Yes you are right, the table has zero records, i just add few records now it is working , thanks a lot for pointing my mistake.

Comment: If the record size is high, some records are skipped and it is not showing in the HTML Table , but if the records in the table are less means it is displaying all the records. what could be the reason.

Comment: Please help me to fix the issue. If the records are more then the order is misleading and records are missing  in the output.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected output in your question?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the sample data.

Comment: The major issue i found is , the output is not going further to  ch3794, col 3794 , but i want to get all the records of the table